# bash history CTRL+R behaviour

Tags: bash, bash-completion

Sometimes I try to search some command by <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and it's not found, 
while I recently used it or search by <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> with success.

Afer I run `history I'm able to find the command again.

Is this behavior is normal?
How it can be changed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> searches backward *from the current position* in the history, so if you already moved that position you'll miss the parts toward the end.

e.g.:

```
themel@kallisti: ~ $ foob
bash: foob: command not found
themel@kallisti: ~ $ barz
bash: barz: command not found
themel@kallisti: ~ $ barq
bash: barq: command not found
themel@kallisti: ~ $ quarg
bash: quarg: command not found
```

Ctrl+R,bar yields:

```
(reverse-i-search)`bar': barq
```

but also *moves to that point in history* - if you subsequently do Ctrl+R and search for `quarg`, you won't find it. This is reset by remedied by using `end-of-history` (M-> by default) to re-set the index.

Comment: When "moves to that point in history"? When the command is executed or while in ^R prompt?

Comment: Definitely "while you're in Ctrl+R" (e.g. if you press Ctrl+R again, it will search from the backwards from the match it just gave you).

Comment: But if I'm in shell and just pressed CTRL+R than also history search is not always located in the end?

Comment: Not always - e.g. if you hit Ctrl+R, type something that matches and then do cursor-left, you end up at the position in the history that Ctrl+R found.